# How to solve underdetermined differential equations numerically?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Consider the following differential equation

$-\dot{x}(t)^2+\dot{y}(t)^2+x(t)^2\dot{z}(t)^2=0$,

[**edited**: or a more complicated one $-\dot{x}(t)^2+x(t)^{1/3}\dot{y}(t)^2+x(t)^{2/3}\dot{z}(t)^2=0$]

where $\dot{x}(t)=dx/dt$, $\dot{y}(t)=dy/dt$, and $\dot{z}(t)=dz/dt$. This equation determines a relation

$F(x,y,z,t)=0.$

The boundary condition is $x(0)=x_0$, $y(0)=y_0$, and $z(0)=z_0$. There can be different ways to represent the solution; one way could be that for a given $x$, $y$, and $t$, we get a value of $z$.

This is an underdetermined differential equation, and it is unlikely there is an analytic solution. What is the algorithm to solve it numerically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an answer to the question of numerical method of solving. But, of course, the analytical solution given below can be used for direct numerical computation.

[image]

One can eliminate an arbitrary function (which is a relationship of the variables with $t$ ) in using the equation :
$$-\left(\frac{dx}{dz}\right)^2+\left(\frac{dy}{dz}\right)^2-x^2=0$$
But this is not yet sufficient to make the differential equation fully determined.

Comment: $\frac{dx}{dt}=(\frac{d\rho}{d\theta}\sinh(\theta)+\rho\cosh(\theta))\frac{d \theta}{dt}$, 
$\frac{dy}{dt}=(\frac{d\rho}{d\theta}\cosh(\theta)+\rho\sinh(\theta))\frac{d \theta}{dt}$

Comment: $f(\theta)=\theta$ works. Unfortunately, the equation I encountered is more complicated than this, and there is no hope to have an analytic solution. So it is very necessary to know how to solve this kind of equation numerically.

Comment: @renphysics : you are right : There is mess in my calculus (now corrected). The main question is not here, but is about numerical calculus. If one want to solve an undedetermined equation, the snag is that there is an undetermined function in the solution. This seems not compatible with numerical calculus, which requires that all the variables have a numerical value. If a unknown function is involved, this is no longer purely numerical, but partly symbolic calculus. I suppose that you will have to add some additional conditions to make the problem fully determined.